# Reactjs handler to change a table´s scrollbar position

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I´m building a ReactJs table that has a vertical and a horizontal scrollbar, like [the following JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dk1x5rvs/)

I need to mimic the following javascript code in ReactJS:

```
document.getElementById("tbody").addEventListener("scroll", myFunction);
function myFunction() {

var elmnt = document.getElementById("tbody");
var elmnt2 = document.getElementById("thead");

elmnt2.scrollLeft = elmnt.scrollLeft;

}
```

And then I tried:

```
  handleScroll = (event) => {

    let tbody = this.refs.mainTable.getElementsByTagName('tbody');
    let thead = this.refs.mainTable.getElementsByTagName('thead');

    thead.scrollLeft = tbody.scrollLeft;
  }

  render () {

     return (
       <div onScroll={this.handleScroll}
          <table ref='mainTable'>
            ... table content...
          </table>
       </div>
       );
   }
```

This is not moving the scrollbar as expected.

How can I move the `tbody` scrollbar to the same position of the `thead` scrollbar on my scroll handler using ReactJS ?

Comment: This is because of the Y scrollbar, which is causing more overflow than the thead. You'll have to decrease the thead width to match tbody's

Comment: @A.Lau, can you please elaborate that into readable code ? Tks.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/dk1x5rvs/1/

The scrollWidth of the tbody ends up being larger than thead because of the scrollbar which takes up some retail space

Just include:

```
var actualInnerWidth = document.getElementById("tbody").clientWidth;
document.getElementById("thead").style.width = actualInnerWidth + "px";
```

In your javascript and it should fix it

Comment: I don´t know if you understood my problem correctly. I need the position the vertical scrollbar always on screen width using ReactJS. This is not working. It´s not a `scrollWidth` problem, but a `scrollLeft` that is not working on ReactJs. It´s about converting the javascript code to work on react components...

Comment: @Mendes If you can't seem to understand the simple fact that the scrollbar ends up taking up width which causes more overflow for the `tbody` than the `thead` which is why when don't align when scrolling (even with an example). Then I don't think anyone can help you. Because the solution is visible in my fiddle, converting it to react is a non-issue.